# How to disable drawer panel in core-scaffold?

Tags: attributes, polymer

I want to disable drawer-panel in core-scaffold. I want to disable menubutton in scaffold toolbar. How can I do this?

[image]

```
 <core-scaffold id="scaffold">

        <core-header-panel id="headerpanel" navigation flex mode="seamed">

            <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar">{{menuheading}}</core-toolbar>
            <core-menu id="coremenu" theme="core-light-theme" selected="{{route}}" valueattr="data-route" on-core-select="{{menuItemSelected}}">
                <core-item data-route="anasayfa" icon="home" label="AnaSayfa"><a href="/anasayfa"></a></core-item>
                <core-item data-route="kisisel" icon="account-box" label="Kişisel Bilgiler"><a href="/kisisel"></a></core-item>
                <core-item data-route="adres" id="adresitem" icon="room" label="Adres İşlemleri"><a href="/adres"></a></core-item>
                <core-item id="guzergahitem" icon="explore" label="Güzergah Görüntüle" data-route="guzergah"><a href="/guzergah"></a></core-item>
                <core-item id="favoriguzergahitem" data-route="favori" icon="favorite" label="Favori Güzergah İşlemleri"><a href="/favori"></a></core-item>
                <core-item id="cikis" icon="settings-power" label="Çıkış"></core-item>
            </core-menu>

        </core-header-panel>
```

Comment: Please show some of you code. Also please edit your question to add some more details to ask what exactly are you looking for

Comment: @Jaffer the post had some more to improve except "thanks".

Comment: oh yes....I will take care next time.

Comment: i think the best way would be not to use core-scaffold at all and build your own scaffold. basically just remove the <core-scaffold> tag from your document and leave it's contents in there place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
    <core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel" narrow="{{narrow}}" drawerWidth="{{drawerWidth}}" rightDrawer="{{rightDrawer}}" responsiveWidth="{{responsiveWidth}}" disableSwipe="{{disableSwipe}}">
    disableSwipe: true, 
Try this also...
mode: {value: 'seamed', reflect: true}
```

Comment: ,unfortunately it doesn't work. do you have another solution?

Comment: wait..I will give another

Comment: i was tried this before your suggestion. it doesn't work.